# Compute cosine similarity against every element of a dask matrix

Tags: python, dask, cosine-similarity

My goal is to find the Top N vectors in a large 3D dask array(~100k rows per side or more would be nice) that are most cosine similar to a target vector. I can get the Top 1, and only for smaller values of n, n=500 takes over 2 hours. I'm doing something incorrectly with dask, but not sure what. Also, is there a vectorized way to get the cosine similarity instead of the for-loop? In pure numpy I can get to n = ~6000 before I have a MemoryError. dtype of float16 is enough accuracy and an attempt to save space. If dask isn't the right tool, I'd be open to something else too.

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

# create a 2d matrix of n rows, each of length n, ideally n is quite large, >100,000
start = 1
step = 1
n = 5
vec_len = 10
shape = [n, vec_len]

end = np.prod(shape) * step + start
arr_2D = da.from_array(np.array(np.arange(start, end, step).reshape(shape), dtype=np.float16))
print(arr_2D.compute())

# sum each row with each other row using broadcasting, resulting in a 3D matrix
# each (i,j) location contains a vector that is the sum of the i-th and j-th original vectors
sums_3D = arr_2D[:, None] + arr_2D[None,:]


# make a target vector
target = np.array(range(vec_len,0,-1))
print('target:', target)

# brute force way to get cosine of each vector in #D matrix with target vector
da_cos = da.empty(shape=(n,n), dtype=np.float16)

for i in range(n): # <----- is there a way to vectorize this for loop??
    print('row:', i)
    
    for j in range(i+1, n):  # i+1: to get only upper triangle      
        
        cur = sums_3D[i, j]

        cosine = np.dot(target,cur)/(norm(target)*norm(cur))

        da_cos[i,j] = cosine
            
print(da_cos.compute(), da_cos.dtype, da_cos.shape)

# Get top match <------ how would I get the Top N matches??
ar_max = da_cos.argmax().compute()
best_1, best_2 = np.unravel_index(ar_max, (n,n))
print(da_cos.max().compute(), best_1, best_2)
```